# How to filter bigger font sizes of a text?

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-tesseract, opencv, python

I've been writing a code to read a text, using opencv and tesseract on raspberry PI. It is working well, but I would like to filter only the title of the text, that is, differentiate the smallest characters from the biggest and extract only the biggest ones.
Is there any way to achieve this differentiation?

Here is the initial code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

while True:
    
    success, img = cap.read()
    
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    cv2.imshow("Video",img)
    
    
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
        cv2.imwrite("NewPicture.jpg",img)
        break
    
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--oem 3 --psm 11')

print(text)
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCLFR.jpg)

Comment: If detection and recognition are seperate steps, then you can filter out small boxes after detection. If they are performed during a single step, like your example, you can still filter out small boxes though that is not the optimal solution. The question is how can you obtain the bounding boxes of the texts. Any search on this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search of the [pytesseract documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/#:%7E:text=Python%2Dtesseract%20is%20an%20optical,for%20Google%27s%20Tesseract%2DOCR%20Engine.) shows that it has:

```
# Get verbose data including boxes, confidences, line and page numbers
print(pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('test.png')))
```

You may get quite a bit of data using this API and the filter the size of bounding boxes.